# Не добавляется класс при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Не добавляется класс activeitem для slideritem при нажатии в чём может быть проблема?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btnprod").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // убираем класс active
      $(".slideritem.activeitem").removeClass("activeitem");
      // добавляем класс active для блока внутри которого находится нажимаемый buys
      $(this).closest(".slideritem").addClass("activeitem");
    });
  });
$('#buyprod').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    if ($(".slideritem").hasClass("activeitem")) {
      var prod = $(".slideritem.activeitem.smlet").text();
      $(".prodname").text(prod);
    }
  })
  </script>
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideritem">
    <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
    <img class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;background:red;">
    <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
    <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
    <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
    <button class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyprod">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="buyprod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="background:black;">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold" style="color:white;text-transform:uppercase;">Заказ товара</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
          <form action="success.php" method="post">
            <p class="prodname"></p>
            <p class="text-center" style="color:white;">Количество, цвет и все детали уточним по телефону. Оставьте свой номер для оформления заказа.</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Довольно странно, у меня Ваш код все добавляет, единственное что поправил это написание тега script. Можете прикрепить скриншот консоли?

Comment: В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте поправить тег script

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:810  - эта ошибка в консоли, на 810 строке $(document).ready(function() { В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Эта ошибка вылетает чаще всего в 2 случаях. 1. jQuery код до подключения самой библиотеки - решение, переместить код под подколючение библиотеки. 2. Версия jQuery которая установлена принимает не "$" а "jQuery", решаеться масовой заменой или подключением новой версии. У Вас скорее первое.

Comment: Спасибо помогло, переместил после подключения, и всё заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно Вы имели в виду что название Вашего товара не попадает в модальное окно? Если да, то добавте пробел между селекторами:

```
$('#buyprod').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  if ($(".slideritem").hasClass("activeitem")) {
    var prod = $(".slideritem.activeitem .smlet").text();
    $(".prodname").text(prod);
  }
})
```